# SQL QUERY: ID from table 1 not in ID from table 2 and table 3

Tags: sql

Beginner here: I have 3 tables with Contact IDs. I want to remove from table 1 all Contact IDs that also exist in either or both of the tables 2 and 3.

```
Select distinct ID from Table1 
where ID not in (select distinct ID from Table2) 
      and ID not in (select distinct ID from Table3)
```

Comment: which database system are you using

Comment: Which SQL dialect (which DBMS) are you using? Syntax of set operations and subqueries tends to vary. Also, what's your schema? Most likely `ID` is already unique or a primary key and you thus won't need the `distinct`.

Comment: Also, what's the issue with your current query? It seems as if it should fit your specification, though perhaps it could be rewritten to be clearer using `minus` and omitting `distinct`.

Comment: When you say "I want to remove", do you actually want to modify the table (which would need a `DELETE FROM Table1 WHERE ...`), or do you just want a result set where some rows are filtered out?

Comment: @Luatic I agree with you, but for a beginner this is a good approach: select first to see if you get the good results before deleting ;)

Answer (score 0):

This `query` will delete the `rows` from `Table1` where the `ID` matches any `ID` in `Table2` or `Table3`.

```js
DELETE FROM Table1
WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM Table2)
   OR ID IN (SELECT ID FROM Table3);
```

```js
SELECT DISTINCT Table1.ID
FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ID = Table2.ID
LEFT JOIN Table3 ON Table1.ID = Table3.ID
WHERE Table2.ID IS NULL AND Table3.ID IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Set Operators:

```
SELECT Distinct ID From table1 
MINUS 
(SELECT ID From Table2 
 UNION 
 SELECT ID FROM Table3)
```

may have to substituate `EXCEPT` instead of `MINUS` depending on RDBMS. basically get a list of all unique (unique beacuse a union does a distinct on it's own) ID's from table2 and 3 and then remove them from the results of what is in table1